# Bukkit armorstand with a passenger

Tags: bukkit

Im trying to spawn an armorstand that is invuable and invisible and has a passenger but I can't do this.
The passenger should be like this: https://minecraft-heads.com/custom-heads/alphabet/5652-question-mark
Does anyone knows how I can spawn the armorstand?

Silvan

Comment: You should provide us with the code you currently have and any errors. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place a head with a custom texture, take a look here: 
https://bukkit.org/threads/create-your-own-custom-head-texture.424286/

If you want to spawn an armorstand, use this:

```
ArmorStand as = (ArmorStand) world.spawn(location, ArmorStand.class);
as.setInvulnerable(true);
as.setInvisible(true);
as.getEquipment().setHelmet(item);
```